# Unicode Symbols

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode

How do I use TeX to generate the Atom symbol?

I tried the following code in XeLaTeX:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{dejavu}
  \begin{document}
  \symbol{"269B}
  \end{document}
```

I got only a blank page with no errors.

Comment: You will need to use a font that has those characters.

Comment: You make two mistakes: First you load the package `dejavu`, but this is only for the Type1 version of this font family. You must use the `fontspec` possibilities instead (`\setmainfont`/`\newfontfamily` etc.). Second you must use `\char"269B` as already written in an answer to this question, for which one yours is marked as duplicate. Because for XeTeX you must anyway save in UTF-8, you could even copy & paste the symbol into your `.tex` document, as I did here: ⚛.